# What is my App Maker database key/name for published apps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

### Context

The Database Key for the *preview* version of an App Maker app can be found in SETTINGS>DATABASE as the Database Key. In GCP, App Maker uses a SQL instance, and within that instance many Databases are listed - including the Database Key/Name from the App Maker preview.

By default, when **publishing** an App Maker app, a new Database within the MySQL instance is created.

### Question

How do I find the Database Key/Name that the *newly published* app is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the deployments settings and click on the **EDIT** option. Then you should be able to retrieve the database key. Here, for your reference:

[image]

[image]

This is documented right here: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment/#databases

Comment: Thanks! Do you find it necessary to remove databases from the default App Maker MySQL instance?

Comment: Also, my teammate and I share an App Maker project. We see TWO previews in one App. They seem to share the default DB. Have you seen Two previews to deploy in one project?

Comment: @Chadd So far, I haven't seen the need of deleting databased from the SQL instances. In regards to the TWO previews, I'm not really sure what you are talking about.